# How to have default button to close tool tip of tippyjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, tippyjs

I wanted to have close button for every `tooltip` how can I have that?

**Note:** I don't want to mess up with design , that is why did not try much , Best solution I'm looking here

**Below is demo:**

```js
tippy('#t1,#t2,#t3,#t4',{
        content: "Error Message",
        delay: 100,
        arrow: true,
        arrowType: 'round',
        size: 'large',
        duration: 500,
        animation: 'scale',
        trigger:'manual',
        placement:'bottom',
        hideOnClick:false,
 });

var settings = [{id:"#t1",pos:"top"},{id:"#t2",pos:"bottom"}, 
                {id:"#t3",pos:"left"},{id:"#t4",pos:"right"}];

settings.forEach(function(sett){
    var tip = document.querySelector(sett.id);
    tippy(tip);
    tip._tippy.set({content:"click x",placement:sett.pos});
   tip._tippy.show();
});
```

```css
div.tippy-dummy{
    position: relative;
    width: 220px;
    height: 30px;
    background: #333;
    color: #fff;
}

div.tippy-dummy span{
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-block;
    background: #715a5a;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
}

.tooltip{
      display:flex;
      justify-content:space-between;
      width: 90%;
}
.btn{
   width: 90px;
      height: 30px;
   border: 2px solid #ccc;
   border-radius: 6px;
}
.btn:hover{
    cursor: pointer;
  background:#f05a27;
}    
.tooltip{
     margin-top:80px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tippy.js/3.1.3/tippy.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tippy.js/3.1.3/tippy.min.js"></script>
<h4>Expected output:</h4>
<div class="tippy-dummy">
   Please click X to hide
   <span>X</span>
</div>


<hr/>


<div class="tooltip">
     <button id="t1" class="btn tippy" title="">top</button>
     <button id="t2" class="btn tippy" title="">bottom</button>
     <button id="t3" class="btn tippy" title="">Left</button>
     <button id="t4" class="btn tippy" title="">Right</button>
    </div>
```

**for better view here is codepen:** https://codepen.io/anon/pen/aPXKZM

Please help me thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 6):

It's actually even easier than Gifford N.'s answer...

```html
<button data-tippy-content="&lt;span class=&quot;closeme&quot;&gt;&amp;times;&lt;/span&gt;There are many like it but this one is mine!!!!!">
  This is my button
</button>
```

```js
const tippyInstance = tippy('[data-tippy-content]', {
  allowHTML: true,
  interactive: true,
  onShow(instance) {
    instance.popper.querySelector('.closeme').addEventListener('click', () => {
      instance.hide();
    });
  },
  onHide(instance) {
    instance.popper.querySelector('.closeme').removeEventListener('click', () => {
      instance.hide();
    });
  },
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The action you are looking for is `.hide()`.

To use this action you have to make a couple adjustments to your code:

1. Add `interactive: true` to tippy settings.

```
tippy('#t1,#t2,#t3,#t4',{
   ...
   interactive: true,
   ...
});`
```

2. Assign the `.hide();` action to the `popper` property in your `settings.forEach` function:

```
settings.forEach(function(sett){
  ...
  tip._tippy.popper.onclick = function() {
    tip._tippy.hide();
  }
});
```

~

## PROTIP:

If you want to hide the popper when clicking a specific element within the popper (`X`, for example) it just takes a little more markup:

1. Add some markup to the desired element `<button class=\"hide\">X</button>`
2. Use the element in the onclick:

```
settings.forEach(function(sett){
  ...
var closeBtn = tip._tippy.popper.getElementsByClassName('hide')[0];
closeBtn.onclick = function() {
  tip._tippy.hide();
}
```

*Updated Codepen:* https://codepen.io/gnowland/pen/wvBzjym?editors=0010